# Cannot find assets when running libgdx app on android, works fine on desktop

Tags: android-studio, libgdx, assets

After getting out of a mode of procastinating, I've finally gotten to the item on the projects todo-list that says "Run on virtual device to see why it crashes".

My project is a libgdx application that I plan on porting to various platforms, the two most important ones being desktop and android. 
During development I've exclusively used the desktop launcher, as it's a lot easier to fire up when just checking minor things.

I did build an `.apk` at one point just to see if it'd run out of the box, but it didn't. Now that I've tried via the virtual device, this is what the log says:

```
com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: Couldn't load file: rifleman.png
```

The same goes for any other assets that my game uses. The files are all placed in `projectname/android/assets`, as I remember learning way back that this was the way to go.

The virtual device I tried with is the stock Nexus 5, but I tried running the .apk by uploading it to my actual phone with a crash right after start, and I assume the problem is the same and is therefore unrelated to the test-platform.

I am currently not using an assetmanager, as implementing this is scheduled for after getting the basic core mechanics up and running. In the mean time I'm loading them as such: `new Pixmap(new FileHandle("rifleman.png"));`

Using android-studio 2.2 on Linux Mint 17 Cinnamon.

Please comment if more info is needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Gdx.files.internal() instead of FileHandle().

From filehandle(string) method info

> Creates a new absolute FileHandle for the file name. Use this for
>   tools on the desktop that don't need any of the backends.
>
> Do not use this constructor in case you write something cross-platform.